# Apache Camel JMS Exception Loop

Tags: java, exception, apache-camel, jms

```
camelVersion = "2.19.1"
springVersion = "4.1.5.RELEASE"
jdk = "1.8"
```

Was working with Apache Camel JMS, XA transactions (atomikos) and Java/Spring. Added some code to handle exceptions that could occur during camel routing and business logic processing i.e. using onException.
Below was actual code before we went into an issue where after an exception occur, onException code handled it like retried as per number specified; sent the control to error handler and then keep on looping and processing same message again and again and doing same actions whenever exception happened and retries failed.

```
onException(Exception.class)
.log("Exception caught")
.redeliveryDelay(redliveryDelay) //delay time
.setHeader("exception", simple("${exception}"))
.maximumRedeliveries(redelivery) //number of retries                
.process("errorHandler");
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research; inOnly and inOut concepts help to came up with below solution to get the message of the queue for the first time i.e. if exception happened and retries failed as well.

```
onException(Exception.class)
.log("Exception caught")
.redeliveryDelay(redliveryDelay)
.setHeader("exception", simple("${exception}"))
.maximumRedeliveries(redelivery)                    
.process("errorHandler")
.handled(true)
.inOnly();
```